# Integration of IOT topics to AWS dynamoDB isn't working at all

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an Rpi from where I am publishing to an MQTT topic on AWS IOT.
Then I created a rule to publish that particular payload into the Amazon DynamoDB.
I managed to send data on IOT topic but I am facing problem in populating it in DB.

I followed this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html by AWS, instead of IOT button I used Rpi and MQTT topic but I couldn't see any entry in DB. Their is no permission issue, I am the root user I have all the permissions.
Can anyone help me out why I am seeing that behaviour and how I can see the payload in table.

Comment: You need to enable AWS IoT service logging, then try this again and see what the actual error is.

Comment: can you please elaborate? is their any reference link available for this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cloud-watch-logs.html